# Exception in unidirectional OneToMany using Ebean with Play 2.2.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I use Ebean with Play 2.2.1 and I am trying to make a unidirectional [OneToMany](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany) join between my entities.

Unfortunately I get the following exception and I have know idea how to avoid ebean using "book_book_id" instead of "book_id":

> [PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Unknown column
>   't1.book_book_id' in 'on clause' Bind values:[197] Query was: select
>   t0.book_id c0, t1.cross_ref_id c1, t1.accno c2 from book t0 left outer
>   join cross_ref t1 on t1.book_book_id = t0.book_id where t0.book_id = ?
>   order by t0.book_id ]

My first class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name="book_id")
    public int bookId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Cross> crossReferences;

    public static List<Book> filterByIds(List<Integer> BookIds){

        if (BookIds.isEmpty()){
            List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

            return books;
        }
        else {
            Query<Book> query = Ebean.createQuery(Book.class);
            query.where(Expr.in("bookId", bookIds));

            return query.findList();
        }
    }
}
```

The secend class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cross_ref")
public class Cross extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name="cross_ref_id")
    public int crossRefId;

    @Column(name="book_id")
    public int bookId;

    public int accno;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [@JoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) for that. Also if you need to set the Join Table, use the [@JoinTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) annotation.

But it seems you have there an incomplete bilateral relationship (you used the bookID to point back to the `Book` entity).

Answer (score 1):

Just tip: Play with Ebean can be quite smart so in many cases you don't even need to annotate JoinTables and JoinColumn, just use proper types where applicable and voila:

**models/Book.java**

```
@Entity
public class Book extends Model {
    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public static Finder<Integer, Book> find = new Finder<>(Integer.class, Book.class);

    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<CrossReference> crossReferences;

    public static List<Book> filterByIds(List<Integer> bookIds){
       return find.where().in("id", bookIds).findList();
    }

}
```

**models/CrossReference.java**

```
@Entity
public class CrossReference extends Model {
    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public static Finder<Integer, CrossReference> find = new Finder<>(Integer.class, CrossReference.class);

    @ManyToOne
    public Book book;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem by inserting

```
@JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName = "book_id")
```

to

```
public List<Cross> crossReferences;
```

Comment: Did I say something different? :)

Comment: I knew about @JoinColumn already but forgot to set the referencedColumnName.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small example, I have a class which contains a reference to itself. Basically it shall be a tree or hierarchical structure. So one parentelement has many child elements and one child element has exactly one parent element.

As long as you name your reference like your class name (e.g. element for Element Class), everything will work...but if you name it something else like parentElement you will face an exception.

**Option 1 with reference name = class name to reference**

```
@Entity
public class Element extends Model {

...

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Element element;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Criterion> elements = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Option 2 Use mappedBy with other naming, e.g. parentElement**

```
@Entity
public class Element extends Model {

...

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Element parentElement;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentElement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Criterion> elements = new ArrayList<>();
```